# Create a list of values from getters of a List of objects

Tags: java, list

Okay so let's say I have a really simple class, e.g.

```
public class Baby {
   private String Name = "alf";
   public String getName() {
      return Name;
   }
}
```

Now what I'd like to know. Given a list of Baby's, is there any niftier/cooler/shorter way in Java to create an array/arraylist of the Baby's names' rather than simple looping through all the babies and adding their names to the new list? The equivalent of this:

```
ArrayList<Baby> babies = new ArrayList<Baby>();
/* some code adding a bunch of babies to the arraylist */

ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Baby b : babies) {
  names.add(b.getName());
}
```

...but *cooler.* Know what I mean?

Comment: *Cooler*? Possibly. More readable and understandable: hardly. Until we finally have lambdas (and method handles) we won't be able to write that much more concise than that.

Comment: @JoachimSauer When in java will be introduced `lambdas` as part of the official documentation?

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry java 8 should include it. But then again, it was originally intended for java 7 :|

Comment: Readable and understandable isn't what I'm going for here. I've been writing code like that for years...I just want to learn some cool tricks.

Comment: @user891876: slightly offtopic, but, switch to scala. Things like this are naturally elegant there.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Guava's](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`Lists.transform`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29):

```
Function<Baby, String> getBabyNameFunction = new Function<Baby, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(Baby baby) {
        return baby.getName();
    }
};

List<String> babyNames = Lists.transform(babies, getBabyNameFunction);
```

The key difference here being that `babyNames` is a *view* of the original list on which the transformations are lazily performed. From the documentation:

> The function is applied lazily, invoked when needed. This is necessary
>   for the returned list to be a view, but it means that the function
>   will be applied many times for bulk operations like
>   `List.contains(java.lang.Object)` and `List.hashCode()`. For this to
>   perform well, function should be fast. To avoid lazy evaluation when
>   the returned list doesn't need to be a view, copy the returned list
>   into a new list of your choosing.

Obviously the syntax for implementing the `Function` is rather verbose - that's Java for you until lambdas. I typically keep commonly used functions as constants to avoid clutter and re-instantiation at the call site:

```
public class Baby {

    ...

    public static class Functions {

        private static final Function<Baby, String> GET_NAME =
                new Function<Baby, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String apply(Baby baby) {
                        return baby.getName();
                    }
                };

        private Functions() { }

        public static Function<Baby, String> getName() {
            return GET_NAME;
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, it's even more code but it's hidden away and more maintainable. Then at the call site:

```
List<String> babyNames = Lists.transform(babies, Baby.Functions.getName());
```

Comment: Lol yeah that's quite a bit more verbose than I was originally looking for, but damn cool nonetheless!  I've never heard of these Guava lists before, and that's exactlythe kind of nifty code I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: And if you think it's cool now, once we *do* have Lambdas & Co it will be as short as `List<String> babyNames = Lists.transform(babies, Baby#getName);` (the syntax might be slightly different, but something like this).

Answer (score 1):

With [GS Collections](https://github.com/goldmansachs) you have a couple ways to do this.  You can use the drop-in replacement for ArrayList called FastList.

```
MutableList<Baby> babies = FastList.newList();
/* some code adding a bunch of babies to the fastlist */

MutableList<String> names = babies.collect(new Function<Baby, String>() {
    public String valueOf(Baby baby) {
        return baby.getName();
    }
});
```

Or you can use the ArrayList with the ListIterate utility class.

```
ArrayList<Baby> babies = new ArrayList<Baby>();
/* some code adding a bunch of babies to the arraylist */

List<String> names = ListIterate.collect(babies, new Function<Baby, String>() {
    public String valueOf(Baby baby) {
        return baby.getName();
    }
});
```

If you don't care about result order, but want to allow duplicates you could use a Bag instead.

```
MutableList<Baby> babies = FastList.newList();
/* some code adding a bunch of babies to the fastlist */

MutableBag<String> names = babies.collect(new Function<Baby, String>() {
    public String valueOf(Baby baby) {
        return baby.getName();
    }
}, HashBag.<String>newBag());

int numberOfBabiesNamedXYZ = names.occurrencesOf("XYZ");
```

If you are using this function over and over, you might want to put it as a constant on the Baby class.

Note: I am a developer on GS Collections.

Answer (score 0):

Well... simply put, no.

That's assuming you're looking for something like

```
ArrayList<String> names = babies.getName();
```

There's nothing like that in Java.

However, you could make a new class to do it for you:

```
public class BabyNameifier {

    public BabyNameifier(){}

    public ArrayList<String> Nameify(ArrayList<Baby> babies) {
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Baby b : babies) {
            names.add(b.getName());
        }
        return names;
    }
}
```

That way, you can later say:

```
ArrayList<Baby> babies = new ArrayList<Baby>();
/* some code adding a bunch of babies to the arraylist */

BabyNameifier babyNameifier = new BabyNameifier();
ArrayList<String> names = babyNameifier.Nameify(babies);
```

Which would create just about the coolest way to systematically retrieve Baby names that the world has ever known.

Comment: Ahah! Actually, I was picturing something similar to your first statement...`babies.getNames()'s`; :P Ahh I can dream.

edit: still getting used to this "enter means send!" feature. I do like your idea as an alternative for anything super nifty though - the later code does look pretty cool!

Answer (score 0):

You want *cooler* way to do it? If you know Spring framework, you are in luck!

In applicationContext.xml, write something like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="babyList" class="com.babies.BabyList">

    <property name="babyLists">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.babies.Baby">
                <property name="name" value="alice" />
            </bean>
            <bean class="com.babies.Baby">
                <property name="name" value="bob" />
            </bean>
            <bean class="com.babies.Baby">
                <property name="name" value="trudy" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

 </beans>
```

Here is the code in normal Java

```
package com.babies;

 import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
 import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

  public class Main  {
      public static void main( String[] args ) {
          ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

          BabyList babyList = (BabyList)context.getBean("babyList");
          System.out.println(babyList);

    }
  }
```

Now you can edit the list in the applicationContext.xml whenever you want to add/delete any name from the list. No need to hard code everything.

You can refer more about Spring framework collection from this link: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-collections-list-set-map-and-properties-example/

Or if you simply want to learn more about Spring, here is a good starting point:
http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

The *cooler* way after the release of Java 8 back in March 2014 introducing Stream API with `.map` and `.collect` operations is like this:

```java
ArrayList<Baby> babies = new ArrayList<Baby>();
/* some code adding a bunch of babies to the arraylist */

List<String> names = babies
    .stream() // Stream<Baby>
    .map(Baby::getName) // Stream<String>; use reference to the getter method
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // build resulting list of names
```